# React native search for documents(.pdf, .doc, .xlsx) in device

Tags: android, react-native, mediastore

I am working on an app to get all documents like `.pdf .doc .docx .ppt .pptx .xls .txt .xlsx`. ihave tried `rn-fetch-blob` and `react-native-fs` but there are giving only directory status.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchdocuments = async () => {
    RNFetchBlob.fs.lstat(RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardDir).then((data) => {
      data.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element)
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
  fetchdocuments()
},[])
```

I also tried this library `react-native-get-music-files` but it returns only the `mediastore file API for android` but don't know how to implement this in react-native. any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I have created a native module for this. code is given below

```
package com.dconverter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ActivityEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeMap;

import java.util.Objects;

public class CustomerMediaStore extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
    private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    private int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CustomerMediaStore";
    }

    public CustomerMediaStore(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
        reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void GetFiles(final Callback successCallback, final Callback errorCallback){
        if(version <= 19){
            getSongs( successCallback, errorCallback);
        }else{
            Thread bgThread = new Thread(null, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getSongs(successCallback, errorCallback);
                }
            }, "asyncTask", 1024);
            bgThread.start();
        }

    }

    private void getSongs (final Callback successCallback, final Callback errorCallback) {
        ContentResolver musicResolver = reactContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        try {
            WritableArray jsonArray = new WritableNativeArray();
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE,
            };
            String mimeType = "application/pdf";
            String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " IN ('" + mimeType + "')"
                    + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE 'application/vnd%'"  // .docx , .xlsx , .pptx  .xls
                    + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE '%application/msword'"  // .doc
                    + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE 'application/mspowerpoint'"  // .ppt
                    + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE 'text/plain'"  // .txt
                  //  + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE '%/%'"   // all type of douments audio/vidoe/ evey thing
                    + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE 'application/rtf'"  // wordpad
                    + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE 'font/otf'"  // .otf
                    + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet'"  // .ods
                    + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text'"   // .otd
                    ;
            String orderBy = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED;
            Cursor cursor = musicResolver.query(uri, projection, selection,null,orderBy);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                Log.e("Musica", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    WritableMap item = new WritableNativeMap();
                    item.putString("id", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(0)));
                    item.putString("minetype", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(1)));
                    item.putString("dateadded", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(2)));
                    item.putString("datemodified", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(3)));
                    item.putString("displayname", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(4)));
                    item.putString("uri",String.valueOf(cursor.getString(5)));
                    item.putString("title", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(6)));
                    item.putString("size", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(7)));
                    jsonArray.pushMap(item);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } else {
                String msg = "cursor is either null or empty ";

                Log.e("Musica", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
            }

            cursor.close();
            successCallback.invoke(jsonArray);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
            Log.e("Musica", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    @ReactMethod private void  checkStorgePermision(Promise promise){

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    @ReactMethod private void checkStorgaePermission(Promise promise){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            promise.resolve(Environment.isExternalStorageManager());
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    private  void  askforscopestoragepermission(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            if(!Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
            {
                askAndroid11StoragePermission(reactContext);
            }

        }
    }
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    private void askAndroid11StoragePermission(Context context )
    {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("data",Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            getReactApplicationContext().startActivityForResult(intent,2296,  null);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getReactApplicationContext().startActivityForResult(intent,2296,  null);
        }
    }
//    @Override
//    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
//        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//        if (requestCode == 2296) {
//            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
//                if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
//                    // perform action when allow permission success
//                } else {
//
//                }
//            }
//        }
//    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.e("Musics", String.valueOf(requestCode +  requestCode));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Here is the usage example

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  NativeModules,Platform, addons
} from 'react-native';


const {CustomerMediaStore} = NativeModules;

const calculateSize = (bytes, decimals = 2) => {
  if (bytes === 0) return '0 Bytes';
  const k = 1024;
  const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals;
  const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
  const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
  return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
const Item = ({ title, dateadded, datemodified, size }) => { 
 let dateModified = (new Date(datemodified*1000));
 let dateAdded = new Date(dateadded*1000)
  return (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Name: {title}</Text>
    <Text>Date Modified: {('0' + dateModified.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dateModified.getUTCMonth()).slice(-2) + '-' + dateModified.getUTCFullYear()  }</Text>
    <Text>Date Added: {('0' + dateAdded.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dateAdded.getUTCMonth()).slice(-2) + '-' + dateAdded.getUTCFullYear() }</Text>
    <Text>Size: {calculateSize(size*1)}</Text>
  </View>
)}


const App = () => {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    requestCameraPermission()
     
  },[])

  const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
   
    if(Platform.OS === "android"){
      if(Platform.Version >= "29"){
          CustomerMediaStore.checkStorgaePermission().then( async(data) => {
            if(!data){
              CustomerMediaStore.askforscopestoragepermission();
            }else{
              try {
                const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                  {
                    title: "Document Reader App Storage Permission",
                    message:
                      "Cool Photo App needs access to your Storage" +
                      "so you can take awesome pictures.",
                    buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
                    buttonNegative: "Cancel",
                    buttonPositive: "OK"
                  }
                );
                console.log(granted)
                if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                  try {
                    myGetFiles().then((data) => {
                      console.log(data.length,"length")
                      setData(data)
                    }).catch((err) => {
                      console.log(err,"error")
                    })
                  }
                  catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                  }
                } else {
                  console.log("Storage Permission is required permission denied");
                }
              } catch (err) {
                console.warn(err);
              }
            }
          })
        
      }else {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            {
              title: "Document Reader App Storage Permission",
              message:
                "Cool Photo App needs access to your Storage" +
                "so you can take awesome pictures.",
              buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
              buttonNegative: "Cancel",
              buttonPositive: "OK"
            }
          );
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            try {
              myGetFiles().then((data) => {
                console.log(data.length)
                setData(data)
              }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err,"error")
              })
            }
            catch (err) {
              console.log(err)
            }
          } else {
            console.log("Storage Permission is required permission denied");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err);
        }
      }
    
    }else {
      console.log("ios Setting here");  
    }
  };

  const myGetFiles = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        CustomerMediaStore.GetFiles(
          tracks => {
            resolve(tracks);
          },
          error => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
      } 
    });
  }

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => { 
   
    return (
      <Item title={item.displayname} dateadded={item.dateadded} datemodified={item.datemodified} size={item.size} />
    )
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={[...data]}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}${+ new Date(item.id*1)}`}
      />
  </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 15,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

further code
to use this CustomerMediaStore module you need register it in MainApplication.java for that you need to create package class
example

```
package com.youPackage-name; // replace your-app-name with your app’s name
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAppPackage implements ReactPackage {
@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext 
reactContext) {
   return Collections.emptyList();
}
@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
       ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
   List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
   modules.add(new CustomerMediaStore(reactContext));
   return modules;
 }
}
```

now add this package in MainApplication.java

```
   @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Add your package here
      packages.add(new MyAppPackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

now you can use it JSX or TSX code