# I want to get all pdf file name and path stored in an android device and list them in the screen

Tags: react-native

I have used react-native-fs & react-native-blob for reading files in device's external storage. I want to get all pdf books stored in an android device and list them in the screen.But I have't succeed to get all the pdf files from the device.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to create a native module in java and swift. one year ago I have worked on such an app where I have to list all documents like (pdf, xlsx, doc, docx, png , jpg ). for that you in android you have to use media store in android for iOS I don't know about that.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68405563/9570734) to to my own answer .

Answer (score -1):

To list all PDF files stored on an Android device and display them on the screen using React Native, you can use the `react-native-fs` library to access the file system and `react-native-document-picker` to filter and select PDF files. Here by I am sharing sample snippet, so you can modify it based on your implementation and requirement:

1. Install required packages:

```bash
npm install react-native-fs react-native-document-picker
```

2. Link the packages using the following command **(Not required for react native 0.60 and above)**:

```bash
npx react-native link react-native-fs
npx react-native link react-native-document-picker
```

3. Request permissions for external storage access and document picking in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Add the following lines inside the `<application>` element:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

4. Create a JavaScript file for your PDF listing component, for example, `PDFList.js`. Here's a basic example of how you can list PDF files:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const PDFList = () => {
  const [pdfFiles, setPdfFiles] = useState([]);

  const getPdfFiles = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.pdf],
      });

      const pdfFilePath = result.uri;
      const pdfFileName = result.name;

      setPdfFiles((prevFiles) => [...prevFiles, { name: pdfFileName, path: pdfFilePath }]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // You can trigger this function on a button press or in your component's lifecycle
    getPdfFiles();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>List of PDF Files:</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={pdfFiles}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.path}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default PDFList;
```

In this example, we're using `DocumentPicker` to select PDF files, and we're displaying their names in a `FlatList`. You can further customize the component and file handling based on your needs.

Make sure you have appropriate permissions set in your AndroidManifest.xml and the required dependencies linked. Also, consider handling permissions and error cases more gracefully in a production app.

Comment: this will ope the directory. and you have to select files form it. not the answer.